# Google BigQuery - sync tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 14 tables in BQ, which are updated several times a day.
Via JOIN of three of them, I have created a new one.

My question is, would this new table be updated each time new data are pushed into BQ tables on which it is based on? If not, is there way, how to make this JOIN "live" so the newly created table will be updated automatically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery also supports [views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views), virtual tables defined by a SQL query.

BigQuery's views are logical views, not materialized views, which means that the query that defines the view is re-executed every time the view is queried. Queries are billed according to the total amount of data in all table fields referenced directly or indirectly by the top-level query.

BigQuery supports up to eight levels of nested views.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't asked properly firts time.
What I want to do is to create new, "materialized" view. I have put together a query, which extracts variables from two tables, and saved it as a new table into BQ. 
Now my question is, if this table is updated as new rows are added to two tables, on which it is based on? And if not, is there a way ho the query can be run periodically, or each time a new row is added?

Comment: Well the best way to get the behavior you want it to use logical views, as they re-query automatically whenever you query it. If not, then you need to create a table with a time to live short enough, and re-create it when it doesn't exist anymore. Doing some kind of "trigger" to push data in your table won't be achievable here

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view or materialized view so that your required data setup gets updated instantly but this queries underlying tables so beware of joining massive tables.

For more complex table sync from/to BQ and other Apps (two-way sync), I finally used https://www.stacksync.cloud/
It offers real-time update and eventually two-way sync. Check it out too for the less technical folks!